# Possible to negate a pattern?

Tags: vimrc

I'm trying to autoload `.vimrc` if I'm not saving it to `.tmp/.vimrc` like so:

```
autocmd BufWritePost !*.tmp\/\.vimrc source %
```

It doesn't work, though.

Comment: How often do you really update your `.vimrc` file? Is it really worth having an `autocmd` for it? You could just use `:so %` when you make a change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if you can negate a pattern. Take a look at `:h {pat}`. Also, if you negate such pattern (if it's even possible), it will also match for `/path/to/a/file/foo.bar` or `/anything/you/would/think/of/bar.baz`. If you want to source only the `$HOME/.vimrc` when written, then you can specify full path like `/home/<USER>/.vimrc`.

Eventually you could use a function:

```
function! AutoLoadVimrc()
  if match(expand('%'), ".*\.tmp/\.vimrc") == -1
    source %
  endif
endfunc

autocmd BufWritePost .vimrc :call AutoLoadVimrc()
```

This will generally check if that pattern doesn't match and then source such file. And because it's called on all files with name `.vimrc`, regardless of the directory, it will act as a negation you're looking for.

Answer (score 5):

@grodniz has already shown you the solution where you simply add a test. I would have written this though

```
augroup ReloadVimrc
  au!
  au BufWritePost .vimrc if expand('<afile>') !~ '/tmp' |  source <afile> | endif
augroup END
```

This is for the generic answer to your question.

Now, you're in the situation of reloading the `.vimrc`. There aren't that many valid emplacements for this file. Actually, when you load your `.vimrc` for the first time, vim sets automatically `$MYVIMRC` environment variable to it. That means, that the autocommand could become:

```
autocmd BufWritePost $MYVIMRC nested source $MYVIMRC
```

as written in [Vim documentation on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vim/3382/tips-and-tricks-to-boost-productivity/20644/automatically-reload-vimrc-upon-save#t=201702141004219471273).